# C++ Nested Loops

Tags: c++, loops, nested

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to code this nested loop.

We have to count bubbles and their respective baubles.

I must prompt the user to input an integer for the number of bubbles.
And prompt the user to input an integer for the number of baubles per bubble.

Each bubble will say BLOP!
After each bubble, each of its baubles will say "bloop!" all in a row, followed by a new line.

my code is:

```
cout << "How many bubbles are there? ";
cin >> bubbles;
cout << "How many baubles are being created by each bubble? ";
cin >> baubles;


while (bubbles > 0) {
    cout << "BLOP!" << endl;
    bubbles--;
    for (baubles; baubles > 0; baubles--) {
        cout << "bloop!" << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't get the 'bloops!' to appear the correct number of times after the first loop iteration. This is likely because I am decrementing the baubles to 0; but I have to do this in order to get out of the inner loop each time and for the inner loop
to print the correct number of baubles.

For  a sample input of 4 bubbles and 2 baubles;
My output is :

```
BLOP!
bloop!
bloop!
BLOP!
BLOP!
BLOP!
```

and it should be

```
BLOP!
bloop!
bloop!
BLOP!
bloop!
bloop!
BLOP!
bloop!
bloop!
BLOP!
bloop!
bloop!
```

Any help is appreciated. I've tried numerous loop methods and included if statements to try to get this to work but I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: How many baubles are left after one iteration of the outer loop? Is there anything in your code that replenishes the stock of baubles?

Comment: There were 0 left. And no there wasn't anything replenishing. The answers below helped me solve this. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (baubles; baubles > 0; baubles--)
```

Should be:

```
 for (baubles2 = baubles; baubles2 > 0; baubles2--)
```

Because it has to reset every time. It would stay 0 forever after the first iteration otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, i recognized that I'd have the problem of the variable remaining 0, but I couldn't figure out a way to correct it. Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the variable `baubles` to its original value every time you iterate over `bubbles`, use another variable `baubles0`:

```
cout << "How many bubbles are there? ";
cin >> bubbles;
cout << "How many baubles are being created by each bubble? ";
cin >> baubles0;


while (bubbles > 0) {
cout << "BLOP!" << endl;
bubbles--;
for (baubles = baubles0; baubles > 0; baubles--) {
    cout << "bloop!" << endl;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "How many bubbles are there? ";
cin >> bubbles;
cout << "How many baubles are being created by each bubble? ";
cin >> baubles;


while (bubbles > 0) {
cout << "BLOP!" << endl;
bubbles--;
for (int baubles_aux = baubles; baubles_aux > 0; baubles_aux--) {
        cout << "bloop!" << endl;

}
}
```